# Find the solutions in positive integers $m^2 + 615 =2^n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

Find  all positive integer solutions $m$ and $n$ of the equation
                     $$  m^2 + 615 =2^n.                   $$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Hint: Note that $m$ cannot be divisible by $3$. So $m^2+615\equiv 1\pmod 3$, and therefore $n$ is even. Let $n=2d$.  We get $615=(2^d-m)(2^d+m)$.  Now the search is straightforward (factor $615$).

Comment: According to PARI GP, the only solution upto $n=10^5$ is $n=12$. So, $n=12$ probably is the only solution.

Comment: Continued to $n=10^6$ and still found no other solution than $n=12,m=59$

Comment: See also: [Finding out the number of values of $n$ and $x$ such that $x^2+615=2^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2238438).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $3 \mid 615$ and $3$ is never a factor of $2^n$, so $3 \nmid m$.

Therefore $m^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 3$ and thus also $2^n\equiv 1 \bmod 3$.

Odd powers of $2$ are $\equiv 2 \bmod 3$ and even powers of $2$ are $\equiv 1 \bmod 3$, so we know that $n$ is even. So say $n=2k$.

Now we have $m^2 +615 =2^{2k}$ so $615= 2^{2k}-m^2 = (2^k)^2-m^2 = (2^k+m)(2^k-m)$

The factor pairs of $615$ are $\{(1,615),(3,205),(5,123),(15,41)\}$ so the possible values of $2^k$ from those are $\{308,104,64,28\}$. Only $64$ is a power of $2$ among these, so this gives $k=6$ and

$\hspace{2in}\boxed{ n=12 \\ m=123-64=59}$

Check: $59^2+615 = 3481+615= 4096=2^{12} \quad\bigstar$