# Solutions to $x^2 +615= 2^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

The equation is $x^2 +615 = 2^n$.
$x$ is an integer and $n$ is a natural.
I started first by taking $x$ as some $2m+1$ as $x$ must be odd. That yields $2^n= 4m(m+1)+ (77×8)$.
By inspection I got one solution at $n= 12$. I am not able to proceed any further. What could be the ways to take this question and what should be the correct "intuition" while starting the question?

Comment: If $n=2r$ is even you get $(2^r-x)(2^r+x)=615$ which has a finite number of cases.

Comment: The factor $615 = 3 \times 5 \times 41$ also suggests thinking about the equation modulo $3$ or $5$ or $41$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding out the number of values of $n$ and $x$ such that $x^2+615=2^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2238438/finding-out-the-number-of-values-of-n-and-x-such-that-x2615-2n). Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5E2%2B615%3D2%5En%24&p=1).

Comment: FYI, there's also [Find the solutions in positive integers $m^2 + 615 =2^n$](/q/1134839/602049). In addition, there's the AoPS threads [Equations with multiple unknowns](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1898291p12968913), [Powers of 2!](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1694526p10853190), [Basic number theory](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2496061p21040166), [Integer solutions](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1190949p5809026) and [Solve this in detail](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1860850p12585945).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

taking modulo $3$:
$$x^2=(-1)^n$$
now, $x^2=-1$ has no solutions modulo 3, so $n$ is even, $n=2m$.
$$(2^m-x)(2^m+x) = 615$$
from here you just have to check cases.

Comment: That would be modulo $3$ (first line) I think.

Comment: Thank you  I get your method