# Solutions for $615+2^x=y^2$ on the integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

This problem is very similar to a popular one, but I found it in this way. I thought it could be solved in a similar manner. This means that $x$ has to be an even number, and then it holds
$$615=y^2-2^{2k}=(y-2^k)(y+2^k)$$

possible pair of factors of $615$ are $\{(615,1), (123, 5), (3,205),(15,41)\}$. Then the way this problem is usually solved is by adding the 2 factors and finding the value for for $2^k$. However this time I tried to susbstract the factors so I could find a possible value of $2^k$, but this means we only have the 4 possibilities for the value of $2^k$: $\{614, 118, 2020, 26\}$. Which none are values for $2^k$ with $k\in\Bbb{Z}$.
Does this mean there are no integer solutions for this equation? or maybe there's something wrong with my reasoning.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I did not assume that $x$ is even, I should have elaborated on that. If $y^2$ is an integer, then the digit on the units place must be one of the followings: $\{1, 4, 5, 6, 9\}$. Powers of 2 can only have the following digits on the units place: $\{2, 4, 6, 8\}$. If $x$ is an odd number, then $2^x$ has either a $2$ or an $8$ as its units place, this in turn means that $y^2=615+2^x$ has either $7$ or $3$ on the units place, which is a contradiction. That's why $x$ must be an even number.

Comment: See [here](https://mindyourdecisions.com/blog/2018/10/25/fun-problem-when-does-615-x2-2y/), or [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-solution-of-615-x-2-2-y) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134839/find-the-solutions-in-positive-integers-m2-615-2n) for the "other" equation $615+y^2=2^x$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, those aren't quite the same; the power of $2$ and the square have swapped sides.

Comment: The $2^x$ and $y^2$ are swapped in my post compared to what you just shared.

Comment: Yes, this is a "swapped" version, which is in fact more interesting.

Comment: Your reasoning rules out the possibility of solutions with $x$ even, but says nothing about the possibility of solutions with $x$ odd. I don't see any way to make this approach work in that case.

Comment: No integer solutions where $x$ is even, no, but if $x$ is odd you'll have to do something else.  But yes, that does prove that $615 + 2^{2k} = y^2$ has no integer solutions.

Comment: @fleablood, once again, great minds think alike!

Comment: @BarryCipra I added an edit on why $x$ cannot be an odd number

Comment: @NotAMathematician, very nice proof!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $x \geq 2$. Reduce both sides mod 4 to get that $3 \equiv y^2$, a contradiction since $0$ and $1$ are the only squares mod 4.

Then the only possible choices are $x = 0$ and $x = 1$. But neither $615 + 2^0$ nor $615 + 2^1$ is a perfect square. So there are no solutions.

Comment: Oh, this is even better than working mod $8$, as I suggested. How embarrassing!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: $615\not\equiv1$ mod $8$, so we must have $x\lt3$.

Comment: Doctor Who has posted an answer with a much better idea than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that prove $615+ 2^{x=2k} = y^2$ has no integer solutions if $x$ is even.

If $x$ is odd we *could* try.

$615 + 2^{x=2k+1} = y^2$

$2^{2k+1} = y^2 - 615$ so $y$ is odd let $y=2m+1$

$2^{2k+1} = 4m^2 + 4m -614$

$2^{2k} = 2m^2 +2m - 307$ which means $2^{2k}$ is odd so $2^{2k} =1$ and $k =0$

$2m^2 +2m = 308$

$m(m+1) = 154$

But $154 = 2*7*11$ can not be so factored.

So $615+2^x =y^2$ has no integer solutions if $x$ is odd either.

BUt that's pretty inefficient and I don't advise it.

(THis could however give us a hint as to considering arithmetic $\mod 4$ and Doctor Who's answer well eventually fall into place.)