# Solving $2^y = 615+x^2$ for $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

How can I transform the following equation:

$$2^y = 615+x^2$$

to something of the form

$$y = \cdots$$

SideQuest:

What would the values of $x$ and $y$ that make the equality True, and how would you get them?

Thanks!

Comment: This can be done in a single step.  Simply take the base-2 logarithm of both sides... you get $y = \log_2(615+x^2)$.  Plugging in whatever value of $x$ gives the corresponding value of $y$.

Comment: $y=\log_2 2^y =\log_2(615+x^2)$. Or if you prefer, $$y =\frac{y\ln 2}{\ln2}=\frac{\ln 2^y}{\ln 2}=\frac{\ln(615+x^2)}{\ln2}$$

Comment: Are $ x $ and $ y $ integers ?

Comment: If you want only integer solutions, it might have been an idea to mention that. $x=59, y=12$ would be one.

Comment: Thanks to everyone! (Yes, x and y are integers)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the solutions in positive integers $m^2 + 615 =2^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134839/find-the-solutions-in-positive-integers-m2-615-2n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sidequest : hint

Assuming that you want a positive integer solution in $x,y$.

$2^y$ can not be congruent to $0$ mod 3.

$x^2$ can not be congruent to $2$ mod 3.

$615$ congruent to $0$ mod 3.

Therefore, $2^y$ and $x^2$ must both be congruent to $1$ mod 3.

Therefore, $y$ must be an even.

This greatly reduces the problem, because now,

$2^y - x^2$ can be readily factored.